# Grid content with hover effect, can not close correctly

Tags: jquery, grid, overlay, addclass

I'm having an issue with my grid.

In hover the thumbnail, I'm having some text which appear - works perfectly.

On click, I have some content which appear in a div under the thumbnail - works fine.

However, If i click to the the close button of that div content, the hover on overlay the thumbnail stopped to work.

Would anybody have any solution to help me out ? It will be fantastic :)

Thank you for your help and time :)

Attach is me codepen where everything will be more clear :):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxBmYa

Below is the jquery im using for the hover effect:

```
$('ul.thumbs li').on('click', function(e){
   $('ul.thumbs li').find('.description').css('opacity',0);
   $(e.target).css('opacity',1);
});
```

Comment: have you got a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please take a look at below code snippet. Unable to work with codepane hence moved your code here:

```js
$('ul.thumbs li').on('click', function(e){
   $('ul.thumbs li').find('.description').css('opacity',1);
  $('ul.thumbs li').find('.description .text').css('opacity',0);
   $(this).find('.description').css('opacity',0);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
                $('.thumbs').portfolio({
                    cols: 4,
                    transition: 'slideDown'
                });
            });

// Utility
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function(obj) {
        function F() {};
        F.prototype = obj;
        return new F();
    };
}

(function($, window, document, undefined) {

    var Portfolio = {
        init: function(options, elem) {
            var self = this;

            self.$elem = $(elem);
            self.$thumnail = $(elem).find('.thumbnail');

            // Options
            self.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.portfolio.options, options || {});

            // Set columns width
            self.setColWidth();

            // On click
            self.$thumnail.click(function() {
                self.showContent($(this));
            });
        },
        setColWidth: function() {
            var self = this;

            if ($(window).width() > 970) {
                var colWidth = ((100 / self.options.cols));
                self.$elem.find('li').css('width', colWidth + '%');
            }
        },
        getContentPos: function(clicked) {
            var self = this,
                thumbnails = self.$elem.find('.thumbnail'),
                contentPos = null;

            for (var i = 0; i <= thumbnails.length; i++) {
                // Get href
                var href = clicked.attr('href');

                if (href == $(thumbnails[i]).attr('href')) {
                    // If its not the last thumb
                    if (i !== (thumbnails.length - 1)) {

                        var cols = self.options.cols;
                        if ($(window).width() <= 1200 && $(window).width() > 970) cols = 3;
                        else if ($(window).width() <= 970 && $(window).width() > 590) cols = 2;
                        else if ($(window).width() <= 590) cols = 1;

                        // thumb position
                        var thumbPos = i + 1;
                        // If there's no reminder
                        var contentPos = 0;
                        if (thumbPos % cols !== 0)
                            contentPos = (cols - (thumbPos % cols)) + thumbPos;
                        else // If we have a reminder
                            contentPos = thumbPos;

                        // Clean & Validate (This fixes weird bug when there's only 2 thumbs)
                        if (contentPos > thumbnails.length) {
                            contentPos = thumbnails.length;
                        }
                    } else {
                        contentPos = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            return contentPos;
        },
        showContent: function(thumbnail) {
            var $href = thumbnail.attr('href'),
                self = this,
                contentPos = self.getContentPos(thumbnail);

            // Remove existing stuff first
            self.$elem.find('li a.thumbnail .active-arrow').remove();
            self.$elem.find('li.content').remove();
   self.$elem.find('.description').css('opacity','');
            // Add active arrow
            thumbnail.append('<span class="active-arrow"></span>');

            // Add content
            var $portfolioContent = $($href);
            var html = '<li class="content"><span class="close">&times;</span>' + $portfolioContent.html() + '</li>';

            self.$elem.find('li:eq(' + (contentPos - 1) + ')').after(html);

            // Animate
            self.$elem.find('li')[self.options.transition](500);
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: self.$elem.find('li.content').offset().top -150
            }, 700);

            // Close content
            self.$elem.find('.close').click(function(){
                self.$elem.find('li a.thumbnail .active-arrow').remove();
                self.$elem.find('li.content').remove();
    self.$elem.find('.description').css('opacity','');
                
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.portfolio = function(options) {
        return this.each(function(){
            var portfolio = Object.create(Portfolio);
            portfolio.init(options, this);
        });
    };

    // Default options
    $.fn.portfolio.options = {
        cols: 3,
        transition: 'slideDown'
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```css
ul.thumbs {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul.thumbs li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

ul.thumbs li .editable{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    display: block;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


ul.thumbs li a.thumbnail:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);}

ul.thumbs li a.thumbnail {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
    background-color: #cecece;
    background-position-x: 50%;
 display: block;
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

ul.thumbs li a.thumbnail h4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #efefef;
    color: #6b6b6b;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.thumbs li a.thumbnail .description {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0,0,0.5);
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 18px 12px;
    line-height: 10px;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.thumbs li a.thumbnail .active-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #fff;
    bottom: -2px;
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 970px)  {
 ul.thumbs li {
  width: 50% !important;
 }
 .media iframe{
  width: 100%;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 970px) {
    ul.thumbs li {
        width: 33.3333% !important;
    }
}

ul.thumbs li a.thumbnail:hover .description {
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 1;
}

ul.thumbs li a.thumbnail:hover .text {
 opacity: 1!important;
}

ul.thumbs li.content {
 width: 100% !important;
 display: none;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 background: none;
 float: left;
    height: 250px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 45px 0 45px;
}

ul.thumbs li.content h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.thumbs li.content .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #c2c2c2;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: -webkit-pictograph;
    font-size: 76px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

ul.thumbs li.content .close:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

ul.thumbs li.content .media {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 200px;
}

ul.thumbs li.content .media img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1080px) {
 .close {
  right: 0 !important;
  top: 7px !important;
 }
 ul.thumbs .media {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 590px) {
 ul.thumbs li {
  width: 100% !important;
 }
 ul.thumbs .media {
  display: none !important;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 590px) {
 ul.thumbs .media {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: block !important;
  margin-top: 60px;
 }
}

.portfolio-content {
    display: none;
}

   body {
                font-family: arial;
            }
            hr {
                margin-bottom: 40px;
            }
            h1 {
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                margin-top: 30px;
            }
            h3 {
                margin-top: 10px;
                font-weight: normal;
                color: #a6a6a6;
            }
            p {
                line-height: 25px;
            }
            a.button {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .button {
                padding: 14px 22px;
                background-color: #cecece;
                color: #333333;
                border-radius: 3px;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .button:hover {
                background-color: #e1e1e1;
            }
            .thumbs {
                display: block;
            }
            .footer {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                margin-top: 50px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <ul class="thumbs">

     
            <li><a href="#thumb1" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/559a567ee4b0d82ab99c24e8/t/565347bde4b0a91f72ad2dc5/1448298431850/3.jpg?format=500w')">
        <span class="description"><span class="text">Get the latest technologies</span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thumb2" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/559a567ee4b0d82ab99c24e8/t/565347bde4b0a91f72ad2dc5/1448298431850/3.jpg?format=500w')"><span class="description"><span class="text">Fast and reliable performance</span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thumb3" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/559a567ee4b0d82ab99c24e8/t/565347bde4b0a91f72ad2dc5/1448298431850/3.jpg?format=500w')"><span class="description"><span class="text">Slick and responsive website</span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thumb4" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/559a567ee4b0d82ab99c24e8/t/565347bde4b0a91f72ad2dc5/1448298431850/3.jpg?format=500w')"><span class="description"><span class="text">Reduce costs and increase productivity</span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thumb5" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/559a567ee4b0d82ab99c24e8/t/565347bde4b0a91f72ad2dc5/1448298431850/3.jpg?format=500w')"><span class="description"><span class="text">Brochures, logos, banners</span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thumb6" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/559a567ee4b0d82ab99c24e8/t/565347bde4b0a91f72ad2dc5/1448298431850/3.jpg?format=500w')"><span class="description"><span class="text">Nunc condimentum magna</span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thumb7" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/559a567ee4b0d82ab99c24e8/t/565347bde4b0a91f72ad2dc5/1448298431850/3.jpg?format=500w')"><span class="description"><span class="text">Nunc condimentum magna</span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thumb8" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/559a567ee4b0d82ab99c24e8/t/565347bde4b0a91f72ad2dc5/1448298431850/3.jpg?format=500w')"><span class="description"><span class="text">Morbi pellentesque quam vitae</span></span></a>
            </li>
           
           
        </ul>

        <div class="portfolio-content">
            <div id="thumb1">
                <div class="media"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/69666609?byline=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <h1>Web development</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mollis nisi sit amet metus venenatis, ut congue turpis aliquet. Pellentesque eget elit sollicitudin, feugiat felis in, ornare diam. Morbi blandit sapien nibh, eu pulvinar tortor luctus nec. Aenean lobortis lacus cursus gravida adipiscing. Praesent in odio porta, placerat felis id, viverra est. Nam magna quam, tincidunt eget augue in, aliquet tristique ipsum.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb2">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>SEO</h1>
                <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse potenti. Integer a posuere tortor. Praesent malesuada mauris massa, non blandit neque tempus nec. Quisque fermentum nunc non hendrerit tempus.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb3">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Web design</h1>
                <p>Ut condimentum eros bibendum metus lacinia, ac condimentum justo faucibus. Nam nec dui convallis, sodales sapien in, gravida justo. Pellentesque pulvinar massa a nisl iaculis, quis iaculis elit tincidunt.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb4">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Project management</h1>
                <p>Suspendisse cursus commodo elit, at tempus felis hendrerit vel. Cras condimentum aliquam mauris at blandit. Pellentesque ac velit iaculis, lobortis nibh id, ultricies ante. Fusce vel urna justo. Maecenas rhoncus vel ligula eget feugiat. Maecenas blandit risus eros, vel imperdiet augue dapibus vitae.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb5">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb5">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb5">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb5">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb6">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb7">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb8">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb9">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb10">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb11">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb12">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb13">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>

            <div id="thumb14">
                <div class="media"><img src="images/media.jpg"/></div>
                <h1>Graphic design</h1>
                <p>Vestibulum gravida, ante ut consectetur dictum, dolor sapien pretium elit, sed tincidunt augue sem a lorem. Vivamus quis neque pharetra, consequat dolor vel, venenatis urna. Praesent diam quam, fermentum vel tortor eget, pulvinar tincidunt velit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, it sees good, but something is wrong. On click, the thumbnail I just clicked on should not have any opacity. but All the others one should have the overlay.

Do you have any idea how I can fix that by any chance ? Thank you for your tie !

Comment: Hello @tibewww, sorry but I will be able to see it on Monday only. Will not be able to spend time during weekend. Thanks

Comment: @tibewww; I have updated the answer. Please have a look at it now. Thanks..!

Comment: Hi vijayP, Than you for your time, but it doesnt seem to work .... on click on one list item, all the other list item should have the overlay effect. which doesnt have  . .  Do you have any solutions by any chance ? It will be wonderfull, thank you

Comment: @tibewww; please check it now.

Comment: awesome, this is it. Just one last thing . . and it will be 100% perfect, I really appreciate your time. Can the text overlay the list item ( when an list item is open) be hidden by any chance ? it should just appear on mouse hover.

You're a legend, thank you !

Comment: @tibewww, may be this is what you are looking for...`:)`! Please note that, I have modified a HTML little bit and added one more css. Now the discription text is inside inner span as `<span class="description"><span class="text">Nunc condimentum magna</span></span>`

Answer (score 1):

you can use following css

```
ul.thumbs li a.thumbnail:hover .description {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

rather than

```
ul.thumbs li a.thumbnail:hover .description {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a small change in your js and this works fine in your codepan.

```
// Close content
            self.$elem.find('.close').click(function(){
                self.$elem.find('li a.thumbnail .active-arrow').remove();
                //i have add this new line for remove opacity of your selection 
                self.$elem.find('li a.thumbnail .description').css('opacity',0);
                self.$elem.find('li.content').remove();
            });
```

Comment: hmm, THank you, but I don't manage to make it work . . .where (which line of the js)  do you add this code ?

Comment: self.$elem.find('li a.thumbnail .description').css('opacity',0); and also i add  comment above the line